# Can't get read access to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, minio

I have created a Public S3 bucket in AWS. I can access it using Access Key and Secret Key from outside AWS.
I can create buckets and add files within the bucket using minio command line and these buckets and files are visible in the AWS UI but I cannot list them from outside the AWS.
I have tried several policies on the bucket to enable listing buckets and files but nothing I have tried allows this.

I have applied this policy to the bucket. I expected this to allow listing the files and buckets but the command just returns with no output.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1693297634765",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1693297627638",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

(base) user@host:/mnt/c/folder/Data$ mc mb aws/test-29-8-23
Bucket created successfully `aws/test-29-8-23`.
(base) user@host:/mnt/c/folder/Data$ mc cp 230601_0000.csv aws/test-29-8-23
.../230601_0000.csv:  321 B / 321 B ┃▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓┃ 922 B/s 0s
(base) user@host:/mnt/c/folder/Data$ mc ls aws/test-29-8-23

Comment: That's not a safe policy to have on an S3 bucket. It will allow anyone to do anything to your S3 objects, including delete them.

Answer (score 2):

`arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*` is only for objects, not for bucket. To be able to list bucket, you also need to add bucket to the `Resource`:

```
"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*", "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"]
```

But using `"Action": "s3:*"` and `"Principal": "*"` is **very dangerous**, as it allows anyone to upload, list, download, delete your objects, and do literally everything with the bucket and its objects.

Its better to have only allow `["s3:GetObject", "s3:ListBucket"]`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1693297634765",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1693297627638",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*", "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The behavior of the bucket is the same with this policy applied. Please let me know if you are aware of any other factors that could be affecting the ability to list the contents of buckets while allowing buckets to be created, files to be copied to buckets, files to be retrieved from buckets and mc 'stat' command to be run successfully on buckets.